# Javascript 'First or Default' function for 'associative arrays'/objects

Tags: javascript, properties

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm storing values in what some would erroneously call an associated array:

The `tokens` object stores.... tokens and a count of documents using that token on a per-db level.

```
var tokens = {'db1' : { '654321': { 'docCount': 1 },
                        '321456': { 'docCount': 2 } },
              'db2' : { '999999': { 'docCount': 1 } } };
```

I can add/remove dbs and tokens and update the docCounts appropriately.
We can assume, due to code omitted for brevity, that if a db exists, a token also exists with a docCount of at least 1.

If a db exists and I need to retrieve ANY of its tokens, what is the best method?
If the dbs held arrays, it would be as easy as `tokens['db1'][0]`... but I'm not using arrays.

I have something like the following, "inspired" by LINQ (please don't blame LINQ):

```
// NOTE: default not implemented here
var firstOrDefault = function(obj) {
  var thing;
  for (var i in obj) {
    thing = i;
    break;
  }
  return thing;
};
```

which would be called as so (simplified for example):

```
var anyToken;
if (tokens['db1') { anyToken = firstOrDefault(tokens['db1']); }
```

Generally returning per the above example '654321' (as this is an object, not an array, order is not guaranteed, but either value is acceptable in my code).

- Is this a reasonable method to get *any* value?
- Is there a better method?
- Should I just suck it up, shove everything into an array, and wrap the storage features that way?

---

UPDATE: I've removed the `default` reference, as an unfound item will a perfectly acceptable `undefined` response:

```
// NOTE: obj.hasOwnProperty not implemented for brevity
var firstOrAny = function(obj) {
  var thing;
  for (var i in obj) {
    thing = i;
    break;
  }
  return thing;
};
```

which would be called as so (simplified for example):

```
var anyToken;
if (tokens['db1') { anyToken = firstOrAny(tokens['db1']); }
```

Comment: If you want to do linq stuff in js, this is a good lib http://jslinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, @pax162 - this is the only LINQ-like function I need, so I don't want to add in a complete library just yet. Do I even need a LINQ-like function?

Comment: @pax162 also, that lib only works against arrays, not objects. If I were using an array, I could just access item[0].

Answer (score 3):

Slightly shorter solution:

```
var firstOrDefault = function(obj, d) { 
  for (var i in obj)
  {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
    {
      return obj[i];
    }
  }
  return d; 
};
```

But yes, it is the fastest way to get any (usually first inserted) key from an object.

I also added a `hasOwnProperty` check to prevent cases where the values are retrieved from the prototype chain.

Comment: Thanks. In this particular case, there is no prototype chain. I was also going to remove the default, but this handles it nicely. I tend to define variables, assign, then return for debugging purposes - and let some other tool compress them away.